# How to compress picture in Android

Tags: android

I want to compress picture before uploding to server, after compressed it will less 150kb, and I have done follow [here](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/), the problem is while the image size more than 6M, it happen to oom. How can I avoid the oom!

Comment: OOM means Out of Memory

Answer (score 0):

the code you´re linking is not handling the bitmaps properly, you have to recycle them. When the Android System handles Bitmaps it recycles them properly but whenever you do it yourself you have to properly return the resources to the system.

Please, read this carefully https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html and apply the propper ideas explained

Answer (score 0):

Parameters ImageFile which u want to resize, height & width of the image which u want in output.

public static Bitmap Shrinkmethod(String file, int width, int height) {

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bitopt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitopt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bitopt);

    int h = (int) Math.ceil(bitopt.outHeight / (float) height);
    int w = (int) Math.ceil(bitopt.outWidth / (float) width);

    if (h > 1 || w > 1) {
        if (h > w) {
            bitopt.inSampleSize = h;

        } else {
            bitopt.inSampleSize = w;
        }
    }
    bitopt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bitopt);
    return bit;
}
```

Comment: It still happen to oom